# How to get a TRUE or FALSE answer in comparing JSON objects for differences

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am comparing two JSON objects and returning only the differences, and it works great. But I need a TRUE or FALSE answer also. Were any new items added to the final array?

Let's assume

**result1** = existing vehicles in file

**result2** = new vehicle data

Were there any new vehicles added to the file (array) ?

```
newItemsAdded = ????? // Your code here

const comparer = async function (result1, result2) {

  //Find values that are in result1 but not in result2
  var uniqueResultOne = result1.filter(function (obj) {
    return !result2.some(function (obj2) {
      return (obj.title == obj2.title && obj.price==obj2.price && obj.miles==obj2.miles);
    });
  });

  //Find values that are in result2 but not in result1
  var uniqueResultTwo = result2.filter(function (obj) {
    return !result1.some(function (obj2) {
      return (obj.title == obj2.title && obj.price==obj2.price && obj.miles==obj2.miles);
    });
  });

  // Combine the two arrays of unique entries
  var result = uniqueResultOne.concat(uniqueResultTwo);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with JSON.  Sounds like you want to do a deep object comparison?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try using lodash, very useful lib where this is already solved.

https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual

```
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };

_.isEqual(object, other);
// => true

object === other;
// => false
```

Comment: wow, nice! That makes this extremely easy. Thanks.